# Docker-compose volume starting empty in container

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose.yml configuration:

```
version: '3'

services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: webproxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /etc/nginx/sites-available:/etc/nginx/sites-available
```

On my host machine I have a `nginx.conf` file at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/nginx.conf`.

Steps:

1. Start the container with `docker-compose -up`
2. Go into the command line of the container with `sudo docker exec -it 687 /bin/bash`
3. cd into `/etc/nginx/sites-available`

Unfortunately the folder in step 3 is empty. My `nginx.conf` file is not being copied.
Is my `docker-compose` file not configured properly, or are volumes not supposed to also copy and start with the host data?

Comment: docker toolbox or docker desktop which one is you using ?

Comment: I'm using Docker version 18.09.9 for Ubuntu LTS 18.04

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't looks anything wrong in docker-compose.yaml , because I used the same file  as mentioned by you to create docker container. It worked for me. check your content inside /etc/nginx/sites-available on your host machine.

Comment: I did check it. It is empty. There are no files there

Comment: can you try to place your nginx.conf present on host machine to some other path and try , update your docker-compose.yaml accordingly

Comment: yes, it worked with a local path like ./user/sites-available/nginx.conf